# member function error in data extraction

Tags: php, data-extraction

I am trying get data from a external source but i can't get the data and i am facing this error.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\merit-list.php on line 38
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on null in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\merit-list.php on line 39

Here is my code

```
<?php
            require('resources/inc/simple_html_dom.php');
            $linksrc = 'http://58.65.172.36/Portal/WebSiteUpdates/Achievements.aspx';
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $linksrc,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 3000,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
            ));
            $file = curl_exec($curl);
            $error = curl_error($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            $dom = new simple_html_dom();
            $dom->load($file);
            $doctorDivs = $dom->find("table#Farooq", 0)->children();
            $doctors = array();
            foreach($doctorDivs as $div){
                $doctor = array();

                // line 38
                $image = $doctor["image"] = $div->find('img', 0)->src; 
                $details = $div->find('tr', 0)->find("td");
                $name = $doctor["name"] = trim($details[1]->plaintext);
                $spec = $doctor["desc"] = trim($details[2]->plaintext);

                $doctors[] = $doctor;
                echo $image;
                echo $name;
                echo $spec;
            }       

        ?>
```

Comment: Does the control go inside the foreach loop?

Comment: Yeah i want to get the data from the external link i mean all images text etc inside the table#Farooq but i am not understanding what is the main issue.

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object is your problem which results in null. What exactly is line 38? Make comment on that line so we can see which line it is

Comment: @Nitro.de here is the line 38

$image = $doctor["image"] = $div->find('img', 0)->src;

Comment: Then your `find()` dont work on line 38/39.. guess the return is null.  Split `$div->find('img', 0)->src;` up into `$tmp = $div->find('img', 0); $tmp->src` and debug what `find` returns

Comment: @Nitro.de i have added this code
$div->find('img', 0)->src;
           $tmp = $div->find('img', 0);
           $tmp->src;
           //$image = $doctor["image"] = $div->find('img', 0)->src;

but now facing this error
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\Skansfinal\merit-list.php on line 38

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\Skansfinal\merit-list.php on line 40

Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on null in E:\xampp\htdocs\Skansfinal\merit-list.php on line 42

Comment: @Barmar but he's doing `$div->find('tr', 0)->find("td")` so is `$div` already `null` or the return of the first find? I dont know the `simple_html_dom` class and what it retuns on the find

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first row of the table doesn't have an `<img>`, because it's the row of headings, so `$div->find("img", 0)` returns `null`. You get the first error when you try to access `null->src`.

The second error is because `$div` is the `<tr>` element. `$div->find("tr")` searches the children of `$div`, it doesn't include `$div` itself, so it always returns `null`. Also, this code won't work in the heading row, either, because it contains `<th>` rather than `<tr>` elements.

You could just skip over the heading row by putting:

```
array_shift($doctorDivs);
```

before the `foreach` loop. This will remove the first element of the array.

And change `$details` to :

```
$details = $div->find("td");
```

Comment: i have used the code as you said
but i am facing this error now

Warning: array_unshift() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in E:\xampp\htdocs\Skansfinal\merit-list.php on line 35

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\Skansfinal\merit-list.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in E:\xampp\htdocs\Skansfinal\merit-list.php on line 41

Comment: Oops, meant `array_shift`